# Multiple wireless keyboards and mice within an office

Tags: wireless-keyboard, wireless-mouse

I'm gathering a list of equipment I'll need for an event our company is attending.

We'll have four computers setup.

I would like to use wireless mice and keyboards in the setup to keep the desks tidy.

Is there anything I need to consider when using four wireless mice and keyboards in close proximity in regard to them interfering with each other?

The reason i ask is a few years ago we used the odd wireless keyboards and mice in the office and they would interfere with each other.

A good answer will cater for X number of devices for room sizes, if interference is still a problem for new devices these days.

Comment: If you buy good quality Bluetooth mice and keyboards (plus adapters if needed) instead of basic wireless models you should find that they can cope OK as the Bluetooth standard is designed for this kind of scenario.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without naming very specific shopping recommendations.

Comment: http://www.logitech.com/images/pdf/emea_business/2.4ghz_white_paper.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You may need to purchase some of the more expensive wireless mouse/keyboards as these can often have configuration software that can allow you to change the device channels to prevent this.

There are other models you can purchase that have a "Connect" button - these often change the channel to reduce interference and "re-associate" the devices to their home computer.

Failing that - you may have no other option but to use wired...

Comment: This answer is correct and but incomplete. The details I would add are the following. 1). If it's possible to get wireless input devices advertising use of the 5ghz band they are far less likely to conflict with each other (because the band contains many more channels) 2). Even as far back as 2014 wireless kb and mice were quite capable. 3). focus on big name brands... there is a reason these companies are so successful in a flooded, highly standardized market. 4). avoid Bluetooth like the plague. Bluetooth has uncountable problems that have nothing to do with signal or interference.